# Adding dynamic Slider values to list and print them and send them as post to server

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, slider

I have asked like this question before but this is some different.

I have dynamic slider get values from list and works correctly as i want.

I want to add their values to another list and print them.

I made this Code but don't work ,i don't know where is the error of my work:

```
Class of new list i want to add values to it :
class MyNewList {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  double degree;
  MyNewList(this.id, this.name, this.degree);
}
```

The page code which contain List and Slider of List values :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './class.dart';
import './class.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
class MyList {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  double degree;
  MyList(this.id, this.name, this.degree);
}
List _getNewList() {
  List newList = [];
  MyList newlist1 = MyList(1, 'sar', 25.0);
  newList.add(newlist1);
  MyList newlist2 = MyList(2, 'Moh', 10.0);
  newList.add(newlist2);
  MyList newlist3 = MyList(3, 'John', 12.0);
  newList.add(newlist3);
  return newList;
}
List myNewList = [];
List _newList = _getNewList();
add_Item_to_new_list(newId, newName, value) {      // function to add values to new list
  MyNewList myNewList = MyNewList(newId, newName, value);
  return myNewList;
}
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 200,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _newList.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                var newId = _newList[index].id;
                var newName = _newList[index].name;
                double _value = _newList[index].degree;
                return Slider(
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                  value: _value,
                  onChanged: (double value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _value = value;
                      _newList[index].degree = value;
                    });
                  },
                  onChangeEnd: (value) {
                    add_Item_to_new_list(newId, newName, value); // call function to add values to new list
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Insert'),
              onPressed: () {
                myNewList.map((item) {
                  print(item.degree);
                }).toList();
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Also I want to send the new list data as post to API server

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by doing this change on this code :

```
add_Item_to_new_list(newId, newName, value) {      // function to add values to new list
  MyNewList myNewList = MyNewList(newId, newName, value);
  return myNewList;
}
```

to this code :

```
add_Item_to_new_list(newId, newName, value) {
  MyNewList newList = MyNewList(newId, newName, value);
  myNewList.add(newList);
  return myNewList;
}
```